# Mod_rewrite question

Tags: .htaccess

It is possible to rewrite my url using mod_rewrite and htaccess where a user could enter:

```
http://www.mainsite.com/12345
```

which the server would translate as:

```
http://www.mainsite.com/index.php?ID=12345
```

By also trying to remove the file extension from all pages, (remove .php) it conflicts and causes a never ending redirect:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ index.html?ID=$1 [QSA,NC,L,R]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?ID=$1
```

Comment: @Zimbabao - thanks for your help! If I wanted to include anything alphanumeric, would I just change the content within [0-9]? Also - would it cause a conflict if 12345 were a directory or a file?

Comment: yeah you can just change the [0-9] to [0-9a-zA-Z] . And for other thing I'll make an edit in the answer.

Comment: @Zimbabao - so I think the rewrite would be:
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?ID=$1

thanks for your help - can you address the concerns from my comment above?

Comment: note - your suggestion also works, and in reality is probably better than just the dot(.) because it limits all special characters

Comment: @blake : I gave regex as per the example :)

Comment: @Zimbaboa - thanks for the help! I assume those are REQUEST_URI's. I have never seen the double f, is it different than single -f? Also, would it be request_Uri or request_filename? I tried both but seems to throw a loop? I found another user with the same issue but seems strange

Comment: @Zimbaboa - yes it did, just got back from a meeting but it worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Zimbabao - one last question, if I wanted to remove the file extension from all pages (i.e. remove any mention of .php), I feel like the following line **SHOULD** work if placed above the first rewrite_condition but it causes a redirect error (will never complete). Placed notes in initial question.

Comment: Try adding L to [NC]and make it [NC,L]

Comment: @zimbabao - won't that simply mean, don't do any additional rewrite rules (last rule)?

Comment: Yes. Thats not what you are looking for for?. For better debugging enable rewrite logs, RewriteLog "/path/to/log/dir/rewrite.log" RewriteLogLevel 9

Comment: I want it to remove the file extension then use the other rewrite condition and rule to use as a user ID if necessary from the original post. I was not aware of the rewrite log so i'm happy you suggested that. i will toy around with it.

Comment: Actually last rule is not really last if you read the mod_rewrite docs clearly. url will be interpreted again (just try it and see)

Comment: @zimbabao - I tried adding the L but still no luck. I moved the directive above and below the rest of the text. I am unable to currently create or view rewritelog files (my apache won't let me create the directory or modify in either the httpd.conf or .htaccess file so I will have to play around with that on my own. I do recall being able to pass a modified URL to another ruleset first (as opposed to being treated as two different rules) so i'll also try and find that link. thanks!